# Is it possible to do forecasts using regression algorithms and only 2 variables?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, univariate

I have a dataset with 2 variables: "_time" and "logins".
I trained a model with the month of MAY. Then I applied that saved model on the month of JUNE (this is unseen).
Is it possible to use a regressor (ex: SGDRegressor) to predict/forecast on unseen data? or somehow does it mean I am overfitting?

This is my code with SPL:

```
 PREDICTING WITH SGDREGRESSOR
 Here, I am calling a saved model (using MAY) and applying it with JUNE.

| inputlookup fortigate_QC_June2019_logins.csv
| fit StandardScaler "logins" with_mean=false with_std=true
| apply "authentication_profiling_SGDRegressor"
| table _time, "SS_logins", "predicted(SS_logins)"
```

This is the plot of the month of MAY. I used ONLY to train the model.

[image]

This is the plot and performance metrics (month of JUNE):

[image]

RMSE: 0.18
rSquared: 0.9667

This is the plot when using garbage data (number of logins but from a different environment)
[image]

Comment: Is the goal to predict logins for particular users, or to predict how many logins will be made in the month of June?

Comment: It is for cybersecurity. I need a baseline of "normal".  So, the first step will be to predict the number of logins.

Comment: If you are interested in predicting the number of logins per month, you can't really do much with a single data point (the number of logins in May).  If you wanted to predict *when* those logins were occuring, then maybe you could do something.

Comment: So, eventhough results look good; does that mean I have nothing?

Comment: Well, you only have 1 data point (namely, the number of logins in the Month of May).  I'm not even sure how you would validate that.  Can you post the output of your data and code for fitting the model?  Maybe I am not understanding your question,

Comment: If you have trained on the data in the first picture, and then applied the model in the second picture, then yes I would say you have overfit.

Comment: This looks to me as if you should model logins per hour of the day, with one model for regular business days and one model for Saturdays, Sundays, and holidays. You might need a different model for whether school was in session or not (summer vacation) and the like.

Comment: @Demetri Pananos Why? The data in the first picture is UNSEEN data. It is the month of june. All the training was done with the month of MAY. And the "garbage data" is the logins from other environment.

Comment: @Aizzac, ah ok if the top is unseen data, then that is completely different.